# Deployed the mvc 4 site on hosting server but the all the links of the site landing to logon page instead of their respective pages

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Deployed the mvc 4 site on hosting server but the all the links of the site landing to logon page instead of their respective pages. I tested my Routes even and the application is running fine on my local.

Here are my Routes

```
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "logon", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Please give me solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Check your web.config for forms authentication settings, and do you have the [Authorize] attribute on your controller class? It sounds like since the user is not signed in, he is always getting redirected to the login page.

Comment: The actuall scenario is the user can able to login and landing to the home page but after login if user clicks on any link redirecting to logon page but not to its appropriate pages. The authentication settings in web.config is like <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Logout" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*"/>
    </authorization>
And i am using customer attribute on the controller classes. [CustomAuthorize]

Comment: So sounds like the custom authorization/login is not properly working. Is the session cookie getting created properly on the browser after login? Are you able to debug and step through the code on this server?